# I want to click on the <li> item in the left navigation of a webpage, using Python and Selenium webdriver to locate it

Tags: python, html, selenium

> I want to click on  **MAKE UP** in the
>   left navigation, Please find attached image and link for the webpage

[Image for the Webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zpdA0.png)

[Link for the  Webpage](http://shop.davidjones.com.au/djs/en/davidjones/beauty)

> I am currently using the below code to click on the item but not
>   getting any result.I am able to acces the **elements by class
>   name('has-sub')**.I can even print them but cant click them

```
obc = driver.find_elements_by_class_name('has-sub')
for ea in obc:
   if ea.text == "Makeup":
    ea.click()
```

Just for the more info below is the html code for the webpage

```
<li class="has-sub" style="height: 38px;">
    <a href="#">Makeup</a>  
    <ul class="submenu" style="top: 0px;">

        <li>
            <a id="SBN_facet_Face" href="http://shop.davidjones.com.au/djs/en/davidjones/beauty/face" escapexml="false">Face </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a id="SBN_facet_Lips" href="http://shop.davidjones.com.au/djs/en/davidjones/beauty/lips" escapexml="false">Lips </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a id="SBN_facet_Eyes" href="http://shop.davidjones.com.au/djs/en/davidjones/beauty/eyes" escapexml="false">Eyes </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a id="SBN_facet_Nails" href="http://shop.davidjones.com.au/djs/en/davidjones/beauty/nails" escapexml="false">Nails </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a id="SBN_facet_Brushes &amp; Tools" href="http://shop.davidjones.com.au/djs/en/davidjones/beauty/beauty-brushes-accessories" escapexml="false">Brushes &amp; Tools </a>
        </li>

        <li>
            <a id="SBN_facet_Makeup" href="http://shop.davidjones.com.au/djs/en/davidjones/beauty/beauty-makeup" escapexml="false">All Makeup </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</li>`enter code here`
```

Any help will be appreciated .

Answer (score 0):

I am able to click using below code.

```
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elements  = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='has-sub']")))
for element in elements:
    if element.find_elements_by_link_text("Makeup"):
        element.click()
        break
innerElements  = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//li[@class='has-sub open']/ul/li")))
for innerElement in innerElements:
    if innerElement.text == "Face":
        innerElement.click()
        break
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: Did it help you?

Answer (score 0):

Problem here is, you are trying to click on the

element while the text is under the  element. So what you are going to need to do is:

```
obc = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//li[@class='has-sub']/a[contains(text(), 'Makeup')]')
```

I tested the xpath on your webpage and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have provided, to click on *MAKE UP* in the left navigation pane, you can use the following code block :

```
obc = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='aside all-open']/ul//li[@class='has-sub']/a")))
for ea in obc:
    if 'Makeup' in ea.get_attribute("innerHTML"):
        ea.click()
        break
```